# Creating pull down menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to creating a pull down menu in a navigation bar. I have the idea how to do it. I am just not succeeding in displaying the menu list on a layer above the "main page layer". The main page is shifted downwards when I click on the menu item. I am using display:none. How to force the menu list to appear above the main page without the main page changing its position?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna do using CSS then try adding CSS property `position:absolute`.

Comment: @asker: If you use `position:absolute`, you will also have to position it using the offset of the menu handle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a CSS-driven menu using hierarchical list items: http://phrogz.net/JS/ul2menu/purecss_testsuite.html